# Timer problem in android not outputting anything

Tags: java, android, timer

I have the following code:

```
Timer micTimer = new Timer();
micTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
         Log.v("Timer", "Timer");
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Which in theory  should every second output a log line Timer Timer, but does not. I understand its probably a better way to use a Handler and use the postDelay() method but this way if working seems adequate enough for my needs. I don't understand what is wrong with the code.

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
   public void run() {
       Log.v("Timer", "Timer");
   }
}
```

--

```
Timer micTimer = new Timer();
micTimer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 0, 1000);
```

TimerTask is abstract, so you can't instantiate it directly - you need to extend it.